# A multiple choice question

Tags: sentence-construction

[Extracted from a textbook of master.get.com.tw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XASrw.jpg)

> 17. ______ us the ability to resist disease, but also helps us build our body tissues.
>       (A) Vitamin C not only provides
>       (B) Not only does vitamin C provide
>       (C) Not only vitamin C provides
>       (D) Vitamin C, which not only provides

The answer of question number 17 is A, which I know is correct, but Why can't I choose D?
They both seem Ok to me.

Thanks!

Comment: The reason you can't choose D is because that would make the text just a ***noun phrase***. The fact that all options start with a capital letter, and the final text ends with a full stop means they're expecting you to create a valid ***sentence***.

Comment: Images are not searchable. Please type the text. :)

Comment: Both A and B are correct to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because *but also provides* requires a verb in the preceding clause which it is countering. **but** joins two clauses both of which must be able to stand on their own. If the first lacks a verb, it is not a clause. With option D, there is no such verb.  The verb there is in the *which*-clause not in the main clause. A verb in a relative clause does not act as a verb in the main clause.

Consider:

> Bill, *who lives in London*, but also has lived in Paris.<sup>ungrammatical</sup>
>
> Bill *lives* in London but has also lived in Paris.

Here, with *not only*:

> Bill, *who lives not only in London*, but also has a house in Paris.<sup>ungrammatical</sup>.
>
> Bill *lives* not only in London but also has a house in Paris.

The subject here, **I**, lacks a verb:

> I, who eat fish, but also like meat. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Grammatical:

I  eat fish but also like meat.

Or you can eliminate **but**:

> I, who eat fish, also like meat.

Comment: But there is "not only" in option D

Comment: That is irrelevant. The subject, "Vitamin C", lacks a verb; the only verb in option D is relegated to the *which*-clause.

Comment: Do you mean that the sentence is not complete since the clause is just to add more information?

Comment: The verb in the relative clause is not a part of the main clause. The main clause needs a verb of its own in order to be able to stand on its own.

Comment: Thank you @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Is this sentence "Vitamin C, which not only...,but also...,is a vital supplement  to human bodies." correct?

Comment: In that case, you have given Vitamin C a verb, **is** (and a subject complement as well), and then it is correct: *Bill, who lives in London but also has a house in Paris, is a mathematician.*

Comment: However, in that case, **but also has a house in Paris** is part of the relative clause,.

Answer (score 1):

> - *Vitamin C, which not only provides us with the ability to resist disease, but also helps us build our body tissues. (Ungrammatical)

This example is ungrammatical because it is a noun phrase with no following verb. Everything after the word *which* is part of a relative clause which gives us extra information about vitamin C. We could put the relative clause in brackets:

- Vitamin c (which not only provides us with the ability to resist disease, but also helps us build our body tissues) ...

The sentence above has a long Subject, but no Predicate (no verb phrase).

For this to become a grammatical sentence we need a verb phrase after the Subject:

- Vitamin C (which not only provides us the ability to resist disease, but also helps us build our body tissues) **is very expensive**.

The example above has a Subject, *Vitamin C (which not only provides us the ability to resist disease, but also helps us build our body tissues)*, and a verb phrase *is very expensive*. For this reason it's fully grammatical.

(All of the examples from the Original question would be much more natural with the word *with*. The usual pattern is: *provide someone **with** something*)