# Should I say "providing me charity," "providing me with charity," or "providing charity to me?"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice, colloquial-language

I'm confused because there's exactly 1 hit for each on them on Google Books.

... [providing me charity](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22%20providing%20me%20charity%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_mP7r3uvbAhUSMd4KHf4pDiEQ_AUIDygA&biw=1855&bih=961)

... [providing me with charity](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=961&tbm=bks&ei=Z0MvW6aLDdGsoATS3LbIAw&q=%22%20providing%20me%20with%20charity%22&oq=%22%20providing%20me%20with%20charity%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...692.1247.0.1391.5.5.0.0.0.0.134.308.2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.gNjFCH9GtYw)

... [providing charity to me](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=961&tbm=bks&ei=aUMvW7aKCJvv-QaJyqeIAg&q=%22%20providing%20charity%20to%20me%22&oq=%22%20providing%20charity%20to%20me%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2519.3609.0.3769.7.6.0.0.0.0.160.764.1j5.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.0.0....0.VVCu1zXuRrM)

What's the correct option? Or at least, the most common/colloquial one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three of your phrases are correct—in particular if you are talking about colloquial usage.

The first sentence omits a preposition, but it is still understood. The use of different prepositions may produce subtle distinctions, but the essential meaning is the same.

There is no "correct" option, just what sounds best to you. (My *personal* opinion is that the first is the most naturally spoken in casual conversation, but that's entirely subjective and I can't point to an objective source for that statement.)

Answer (score 1):

The verb **provide** takes the following:

direct object:

indirect object + direct object:

(indirect) object + prepositional phrase complement [that which is provided]:

direct object + prepositional phrase adjunct [recipient, beneficiary]:

> Trees provide food.
>
> Trees provide us food.
>
> Trees provide us with food.
>
> Trees provide food to us.

Comment: But https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/provide says explicitly "✗ Don’t say: We provide parents information." Hmmm...

Comment: You will have to take the matter up with ldoceonline.  Here's an example https://books.google.com/books?id=2RaavytYnyYC&pg=PA40&dq=%22provide+us+all%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuz7jBsuzbAhVOwVkKHeLrD8kQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=%22provide%20us%20all%22&f=false  And if you have any lingering doubts: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22provide%20us%20information%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: Or this: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22provide%20researchers%20access%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: You're right. However, see how Araucaria phrased it [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/128986/3395) (the last two sentences in parentheses) – I think that's a good piece of advice for learners. (The Google Books Ngram Viewer results are also somewhat disfavoring that pattern last time I checked.)

Comment: I think one's sense of what is natural here will depend on how often one encounters the **provide researchers access** pattern.

Answer (score -1):

The second and the third ones are correct or at least more common.

> - **provide something for somebody** e.g. We are here to provide a service for the public.
> - **provide somebody with something** e.g. We are here to provide the public with a service.
> - **provide something to somebody** e.g. The charity aims to provide assistance to people in need.

Source: [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/provide)